# Process JSON file on filesystem using a @GET?

Tags: json, file-io, jersey

I am using Jersey & Jackson to process Restful based web services with JSON.

Lets say that I have json text files (e.g. customer.json) that reside on a filesystem...

Is it possible to process that json file from a Restful method which implements @GET?

Would I need to upload the file using Java's File I/O inside the @GET method?

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: http get queries are length limited. unless you're sending relatively short (<512 bytes at most) json strings, you're likely to end up with corrupted garbage when the browser and/or webserver chop your json string up in the middle somewhere.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What are you trying to do? Where is this filesystem: on the server, on a client? Do you want to upload it? Why do you want to use GET?

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file is small, yes, you can encode it at the end of the URL.

```
GET www.mydomain.tld/process/json/?string={ json: "testest" }
```

But realistically, no. As a work around you could send a reference to the file, like a url where it's located or a temp GUID where you previously POSTed it to the server.

```
GET www.mydomain.tld/process/json/?file=http://www.otherdomain.tld/file.json
```

Or, the first POST to another controller with the whole file contents would return a guid that the server can use in the subsequent GET request to get the uploaded file from local storage or a database.

```
guid <-- POST www.mydomain.tld/upload/json/ {BIG JSON FILE}
GET www.mydomain.tld/process/json/?guid={guid}
```

Answer (score 0):

GET is not recommended as it is considered a "safe" method. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-51. You should use POST or PUT depending on the end result of your upload: PUT in case subsequent uploads do not change the state of the server or POST otherwise.

Jersey has a nice support for uploading. Here is a nice example of how to do implement an upload: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/.

In case you don't want to save the file to disc as in the example, you can store in in memory using a ByteArrayOutputStream instead. Then create a string out of it:

```
String str = new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Then create your JSONObject:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObhect(str);
```